# Does the ambient temperature at the time of reading effect the readibility of cds?

Tags: temperature, compact-disc

While going through a lot of old data CDs (all round about 20 yrs old) I noticed, that the ambient temperature of the CD and the CD-Drive seems to affect the readibility of the CD if both of them are rather warm, some of the CDs cannot be read and return weird read errors, but if they are cooled down to room temperature, the very same CDs are readable again. Is that just a coincidence or is there actually a connection between the ambient temp and the readibility? And if so, why is that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambient temperatures can definitely affect electronics, causing voltages to drift as resistor and capacitor values change slightly over a temperature range.

Those drifts can mean that something goes out of specification, and various parts of the circuit operate *oddly*. An amplifier working on small analogue signals from the laser may not boost the signal up to a level where the rest of the circuit can reliably tell if it is seeing a 0 or a 1.

A power supply also does not like extreme heat and past a certain point may end up putting out a lower voltage or simply brown out, again causing erratic behaviour from the rest of the circuitry. Power supplies all generate some heat during their operation and will sink that heat into the air and surrounding parts, a high ambient temperature can make it harder for the power supply to get rid of heat and so cause it to fall over sooner. If you're interested many manufacturers list a "derating curve" for their supplies, and it will show how much of its rated power it can supply when it starts to overheat.

I have a USB Blu-rau drive that if used in a sustained fashion for several hours, will simply give up and refuse to read disks. Given a half hour break to cool down seems to let it work normally again. It could be that the 5V from USB is slightly low under use (I've seen USB sag to 4.8V under heavy load) and it may be on the cusp for the power supplies and electronics powering the drive.

Comment: That makes sense, I am also using a usb cd-drive. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ductTapeIsMagic I've added a bit more info, specifically about power supplies, which is the most likely problem. My suspicion would be that when in use initially the power supply in the drive itself jumps up to a moderately high temperature, but because of the parts around it can sink heat into the chassis and board and so on. As those parts warm up so does the power supply and it reaches the point where its derating curve (temperatures where it can no longer reliably supply full power) comes into play and it starts to fail, after that everything else starts acting odd until it cools down.

Comment: Ambient temperatures plat a part in it failing sooner because everything is already hotter to begin with and it doesn't take as much heat to reach the point where things fall over.

Comment: Thanks again very much! Couldn't find the datasheet of my drive though, probably because it was quite cheap. I'll probably do the CD-stuff in the basement now, much cooler there :)